# PDFBox splits data inside html tags like <td> into separate pages . How to specify where to split pages?

Tags: java, html, pdfbox

I am converting an HTML file to a pdf using pdfbox and when it generates pages, it divides data inside HTML tags (like ) at the bottom into two pages.
How can I specify some sort of sections (or groups) to where the data can be separated.
So that it won't split data inside tags like

```
public byte[] createPDF(String htmlData) {
        try {
            
            byte[] pdfCon = super.createPDF(htmlData);
            
            pdfCon = drawVerticalLine(pdfCon);

            return pdfCon;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
    
    protected byte[] drawVerticalLine(byte[] content )
            throws Exception {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(content);
        int pageCount = doc.getNumberOfPages();
        PDPageContentStream canvas;
       ...
     }
```

Comment: I'm not aware of PDFBox featuring HTML-to-PDF conversion.

Comment: use openhtmltopdf https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<style>
page-inside-avoid {
  display:block;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  height:120px;
}
</style>
<body>
<page-inside-avoid>
//renderer will try to avoid page breaks inside this tag 
</page-inside-avoid>
</body>
```